# :First-Child and :nth-child() not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

### [**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fg3nco9w/)

At the bottom of my CSS, please find the following;

```
.AdminPanelLayout .Option:nth-child(1) {
    background:#000000;
    margin-left:20px;
}
```

The `background:#000000;` is not needed, it is there for testing purpposes. As for the `margin-left:20px;` is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Can you first tell us what it is supposed to do?

Comment: What child are you trying to style?

Comment: Well first-child targets the first element in the parent so it won't work for your code since the first element is the title

Comment: But the `<div class="Option">` isn't the first child, so it won't match.

Comment: I've used this so many times and `:nth-child(1)` , I'm pretty confused I must be having one of those moments of dumbness! :(

Comment: `:first-of-type` does not work @chipChocolate.py

Comment: @TimMarshall `:nth-child` matches elements, not classes, so it will look at the children of the parent container and if the first one has the class `Option` then match it, otherwise ignore it.

Comment: try div.Option:nth-of-type(2) {
 background:#000000;
    margin-left:20px;
}

Comment: Thank you @taesu, make this an answer and I'll accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems you are missunderstanding the concept of `first-child`. It does not look for the first child that meets the selector. Instead, it looks for the selector who is also the first child in its container.

To select the first `.Option` in your case:

```
<div class="AdminPanelLayout">
    <div class="Title">
        2). Choose Admin Panel Layout
    </div>
    <div class="Option">
```

You would have to try another approaches, like:

- Target for its index, in this case 2: `.AdminPanelLayout .Option:nth-child(2) {`
- Target it as sibling (the immediate first after the title) `.AdminPanelLayout .Title + .Option {`

You'll have to play around a little

Answer (score 1):

```
.AdminPanelLayout .Option:nth-of-type(2) {
    background:#000000;
    margin-left:20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fg3nco9w/1/

Comment: How about an explanation as to what you did, why it works, and why `.Option:nth-child(1)` fails?